# HTML navigation problems

Tags: html, menu, navigation, hover, nav

I've got this navigation code that works great, but I can't figure out the most inner part.

`ul -> li -> span -> ul -> li -> ul -> li ->`  `ul -> li` this last ul, li block

So basically, when someone hovers over work, I want the Freelance work to appear, else hidden, just like My portfolio. But which part is wrong in this code? Freelance work appears all the time.

[jsfiddle code here](http://jsfiddle.net/F4LLCON/De7cM/)

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend using some jquery. You should also look in to using classes and id's, they come in handy when dealing with nested code -> http://jsfiddle.net/hNneu/

jQuery:

```
$("#work-id").hover(
  function () {
    $('#freelance-work-id').show();
  },
  function () {
    $('#freelance-work-id').hide();
  }
);
```

HTML:

```
<li id="work-id"><a href="work.html">Work</a>
     <ul id="freelance-work-id">
         <li>
             <a href="#">Freelance work</a>
         </li>
     </ul>
</li>
```

CSS:

```
#freelance-work-id {
    display:none;
}
```

Comment: I got a problem, in jsfiddle it works great, but when I copy all the code to my website, it doesn't work? EDIT, Oh wait, I think I got it, need to import the jquery library. I will test it right away